# Natural embedding of Q with the Euclidean metric in R with the Euclidean metric is an isometric embedding.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The book I'm reading states this:  The natural embedding of $Q$ with the Euclidean metric in $R$ with the Euclidean metric is an isometric embedding.

What is the "natural embedding" of Q with the Euclidean metric?  I understand that an isometric embedding is an onto map $f : (X,d) \rightarrow (f(X), d_2)$ such that $d(x_1,x_2) = d_2(f(x_1),f(x_2)),$ for all $x_1, x_2$ in $X$.

But the only isometric embedding that works from what I can figure  is $f(x) = x$ because $|x_1-x_2| = |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = |x_1-x_2|$.

Comment: The identity embedding is rather natural, is it not?

Comment: In response to your last sentence, there are other isometric embeddings, such as $f(x)= \pm x+q$  for any rational $q$.

Comment: An embedding need not be onto, and if it were the domain and codomain of the map would be the same. Instead of saying onto one should say embeddings are injective (one-to-one).